# Why does my iPhone use my location when I tell it not to?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, privacy

Why does my iPhone use my location even though I tell it not to? As you can see from the Time Zone setting, I have it switched off, yet it says that my location was recently used. Why bother having a switch at all?

[image]

Comment: A grey icon means it was used within the last 24 hours. Did you perhaps switch it off recently?

Comment: @DonielF No. No. No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known defect that started with iOS 10.3.  Dozens of Apple fan sites, including Apple's own discussion forums, are filled with people complaining about the bug.

According to some people on [this Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7909881?start=15&tstart=0), Apple is now considering this 'expected behavior' and doesn't have any plans to fix it.  I'd take that with a grain of salt because it's just one person saying they were told this by an Apple support person.

I'd recommend you file a [bug report](https://getsupport.apple.com/) as well as provide [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) about your displeasure.